# How does the while loop work here?

Tags: c, termination

The following code I came across though I have basic idea of C. I still get the logic of below code.

1. How does the loop terminate and when does the loop terminate — at what condition?
2. At last `counter` becomes zero, but why doesn't the loop continue to execute with -1, -2 and instead it terminates?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void);
static int count = 5;
int main()
{
    while (count--)
    {
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}

void func(void)
{
    static int i = 5;
    i++;
    printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

Output:

```
i is 6 and count is 4
i is 7 and count is 3
i is 8 and count is 2
i is 9 and count is 1
i is 10 and count is 0
```

Comment: while(0) will evaluate to false. This will break the while loop

Answer (score 1):

`while(term)`

When term(condition/variable/function) evaluates to 0 then while loop terminates.

`count--`  return the value of count then decrements it.

So when count-- return zero loop terminates. Which will be when count has value 0.
Also see comment.

C takes 0 as false and rest as true so the while loop will break when condition evaluates to false (0).

Comment: Actually, the loop goes through a final iteration after `count` becomes zero, because `while (count--)` evaluates `count` and then decrements it, so there is a cycle where `count` is `1` before it is decremented to zero, but the loop continues for one more iteration because the value of the post-decrement expression is `1`, which evaluates to true so the loop condition is still satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Here the loop terminates when count becomes 0 because in C, 0 acts like false in Java (boolean type) and the condition is therefore false. The loop exits.

when count=

0 — loop condition is false

non 0 — loop condition is true

Comment: You need to be quite careful.  The condition is `while (count--)`, so in the iteration when `count` starts at `1`, the condition evaluates to true (because `1` is not `0`) but the variable `count` is decremented to `0` and has the value `0` in the body of the loop.

Comment: yeah as its post decrement the value is taken first then the decrementation is done

Answer (score 1):

The conditional of the `while` loop, `count--`, evaluates to `1` when the value of `count` is `1` before the evaluation of the expression. The side effect of the evaluation of the expression is that the value of `count` is decremented by `1`, i.e. its value becomes `0`.

That's why you see

```
i is 10 and count is 0
```

as the output.

When the conditional of the loop is evaluated next time, the value of the expression is `0` and the value of `count` is set to `-1`. Since the value of the expression is `0`, execution of the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

count-- is [**post**-decrement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators). So, the value of `count` is not decremented instantly in the `while` condition. It is decremented afterwards (just after the evaluation of `while` condition). Thus, `while` continues to run when `count = 1` and `count--` is done. But just after the entering `while`, `count becomes 0`, thus, next time when the condition evaluation reaches, `while` breaks.

In simple terms, `count is equal to 5` and you expect it to run 5 iterations (under simple flow), so it runs `4 to 0`. If you want it other way around, you can do, *try this and see for yourself*

```
while( 0 != count )
{
   func() ;
   count-- ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ any expression which results in zero (0) will be evaluated to false if the expression is used in place of condition. Look -

```
if(0){
  //never reached; never executed
}
```

Similarly any non-zero in an expression will be evaluated to `true` -

```
if(5){
   //always reached and executed
}
```

This fact is applicable for condition in `while-loop`  -

```
int i = 5;
while(i){
  //do something

  i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**question1:how does the loop terminates and when does the loop terminates at what condition.**

*ans:* The while loop start with count = 5. The loop condition satisfied because ***count is non-zero*** .But immediately count value is decresed by one and becomes count =4, due to count--. So the Output is

> i is 6 and count is 4

Upto count =1,it continues.Count =1 too satisfy loop condtion. But immediately count-- happens and now count =0. So the output is

> i is 10 and count is 0

So on next check loop condition not satisfied (Count = 0) and the loop terminates.

**question2:at last counter becomes zero,but why the loop don't continue to exist to -1,-2 instead it terminates?**

*ans:* When the loop condition becomes zero it creates a FALSE condition. So it gets terminated there.

Note : Only zero value in the condition block terminates the loop. If it is less than zero it will not.

check this.

```
void func(void);
static int count = -5;
main()
{
    while (count++)
    {
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}

void func(void)
{
    static int i = 5;
    i++;
    printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

creates output as

```
i is 6 and count is -4
i is 7 and count is -3
i is 8 and count is -2
i is 9 and count is -1
i is 10 and count is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The while expression is *boolean*; the *integer* expression `count--` is therefore implicitly cast to boolean such that any non-zero value is `true` and zero is `false`.